# Add column from another data.frame based on multiple criteria

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames:

```
cars = data.frame(car_id=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5), 
                  max_speed=c(150,180,185, 200, 210, 230,235),
                  since=c('2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2007-10-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2009-11-18'))

voyages = data.frame(voy_id=c(1234,1235,1236,1237,1238),
                     car_id=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                     date=c('2000-01-01', '2002-02-02', '2003-03-03', '2004-04-04', '2010-05-05'))
```

If you look closely you can see that the *cars* occasionally has multiple entries for a `car_id` because the manufacturer decided to increase the max speed of that make. Each entry has a date marked by *since* that indicates the date from which the actual max speed is applied.

**My goal:** I want to add the `max_speed` variable to the `voyages` data frame based on the values found in `cars`. I can't just join the 2 data frames by `car_id` because I also have to check the `date` in `voyages` and compare it to *since* in `cars` to determine the proper `max_speed`

**Question:** What is the elegant way to do this without loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

Merge the two datasets, including duplicated observations in "cars". 
Drop any observations where the date for "since" is later than the date for "date". Order the dataset so most recent dates are first, then drop duplicated observations for "voy_id"--this ensures that where there are two dates in "since", you'll only keep the most recent one that occurs before the voyage date.

```
z <- merge(cars, voyages, by="car_id")
z <- z[as.Date(z$since)<=as.Date(z$date),]
z <- z[order(as.Date(z$since), decreasing=TRUE),]
z <- z[!duplicated(z$voy_id),]
```

Also curious to see if someone comes up with a more elegant, parsimonious approach.

Comment: It still feels a bit hackish but it's the best one without loops so I'll use it :)